# Unable to display Image as background in tkinter using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, tkinter

I was trying to give a Background image to my Tkinter application but there is no error and unable to see the image also. I am using trying to make the navigation screen in which I am trying put different image background.

I am using mentioned below lines in actual code to put the image in the frame

```
    Frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master)
    Frame2.pack(side="left", fill="both", pady=10, anchor='w', expand=True )
    photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/BG.jpg")
    label = tk.Label(Frame2, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    label.place(x=0, y=0)
```

**Actual Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.ard_stat = read_json(JSON_PATH)
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def loopCap(self):
        with open(JSON_PATH) as json_file1:
            self.data = json.load(json_file1)
            #print(self.data)
        if self.data['status'] == 'ACTIVE': #and (self.data['RH_img']!= 'null' or self.data['LH_img']!= 'null')
            a = self.text.set(self.data['status'])
            b = self.text1.set(self.data['RH_cnt'])
            c = self.text2.set(self.data['LH_cnt'])
            d = self.text3.set(self.data['barcode'])
            return self.text, self.text1, self.text2, self.text3, self.data

    def next_save(self):
        new_string = self.data['barcode']
        new_folder = os.path.join(DATA_PATH,new_string)
        if os.path.exists(new_folder):
            #print("Folder Already Exists If Condition")
            tk.messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Folder Already Exists")
        else:
            #os.isfile(new_string)
            #print("Folder Already Exists")
            #tkMessageBox.showinfo("Info", "Folder Already Exists")
            #print("Make Directory Else Condition")
            json_dict = read_json(JSON_PATH)
            json_dict.update({"frontend_status": "True"})
            dump_to_json(json_dict, JSON_PATH)
            os.mkdir(new_folder)
            for i in range(0,len(data)):
                folder_name = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, new_string, data[i])
                os.mkdir(folder_name)
                files = [('All Files', '*.*'),
                         ('Python Files', '*.py'),
                         ('Text Document', '*.txt')]
                file = asksaveasfile(initialdir=folder_name, filetypes=files, defaultextension=files)
            json_dict = read_json(JSON_PATH)
            json_dict.update({"frontend_status": "False"})
            dump_to_json(json_dict, JSON_PATH)

            self.master.after(500, self.loopCap)

    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master.geometry("1000x700+%d+%d" % (((self.master.winfo_screenwidth() / 2.) - (1280 / 2.)), ((self.master.winfo_screenheight() / 2.) - (720 / 2.))))
        #self.master.state('zoomed')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        #myvar = self.master
        Frame1 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        Frame1.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", pady=10, anchor='w')
        Frame2 = tk.Frame(self.master)
        Frame2.pack(side="left", fill="both", pady=10, anchor='w', expand=True )
        photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/BG.jpg")
        label = tk.Label(Frame2, image=photo)
        label.image = photo
        label.place(x=0, y=0)
        tk.Label(Frame2, text='  Decal Check  ', font=('arial', 25, 'bold'), bg='powder blue',
                 fg='black', anchor='w').grid(column=0,pady=2)

        b = tk.Button(Frame2, text="Add New Files", command= self.next_save)
        b.grid(row=11, column=1, pady=5, sticky='w')

        self.master.after(500, self.loopCap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Suggestions on this will be really helpful

**EDIT**
As per the suggested answer, I used `photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="images/BG.jpg")` for `png`  and  `ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="images/BG.jpg")` but every time my screen is dislayed as mentioned below image:

[image]

**NOTE**: I am using Pycharm to check my Window Background

Comment: you import `ImageTk` but you don't use it to load `.jpg` image. Older `tkinter` worked only with `.gif`. New `tkinter` can work also with `.png` but it still doesn't work with `.jpg` and you have to use `Image`, `ImageTk` from `PIL` - see link in answer.

Comment: I use ```photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)``` also but still facinhg the same issue

Comment: I tested your code on Linux Mint 19.2, Python 3.7. if I use `.png` in `tk.PhotoImage(file="image.png")` then I see image - but with `.jpg` I get error message (when I run in console/terminal). If I use `.jpg` in `photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image.jpg"))` then I see image.

Comment: @furas I used the same way you told me but still, it's showing the frame without Image, I have mentioned the snapshot also, ***Note*** the image which is available on the screen does not background it's just the label I have mentioned with other Images with in the same frame

Comment: I tested with your code and I saw image. But I don't have your JSON data so it doesn't add other elements. SO maybe problem is that all widgets have gray background (which you can't change on some systems) and image is hidden behind other widgets. Create minimal working code with image and without other widgets to test it.

Comment: BTW: and use normal terminal/console/cmd.exe instead of PyCharm to see error messages.

Comment: Hey, It worked there was some I dint put ```lab_1.image = photo``` and after that it worked perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:
https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Please convert your JPG image to the appropriate format.

Comment: I converted it in ```gif``` format still not able to upload the image

Comment: I have tried your code with the PNG image, and it worked